# Laravel Route Redirect with URL Parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to generate a unique id and then redirect to a different route with id in the url parameter. But I am getting error as :

"Route [sequences] not defined."

Here is my route defined:

```
Route::get('/sequences_create','SequencesController@create');
Route::get('/sequences/{id}', 'SequencesController@show');
```

Here is the create function on the sequences controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $uniq = 'seq'. uniqid();
        $seq = new Sequences;
        $seq->id = $uniq;
        $seq->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $seq->name = 'New Sequence'; //temp name
        $seq->save();
        return redirect()->route('sequences', ['id' => $uniq]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have not set a name for your route by `name()` method.

try it:

```
Route::get('/sequences_create','SequencesController@create')->name('sequances.create');
Route::get('/sequences/{id}', 'SequencesController@show')->name('sequances.show');
```

then:

```
public function create()
    {
       //...
        return redirect()->route('sequences.show', ['id' => $uniq]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to name your route.

```
Route::get('/sequences_create','SequencesController@create')->name('sequences.create');
Route::get('/sequences/{id}', 'SequencesController@show')->name('sequences.show');
```

Then change your redirect to:

`return redirect()->route('sequences.show', ['id' => $uniq]);`